# WPF menus are not positioned normally

Tags: wpf, windows-7, .net-4.0, windows-7-x64

I've been happily writing my new program and it worked like a charm. It was simple and didn't need a menu at first until I decided to add more functionality so a menu was required. Baam! The image below explains my problem better.

[image]

Noticed how the file menu is aligned? The app in the picture is a test app just to see if I added something in my other app that may have caused the problem. Even though the project was brand new it still showed up. I can't understand why it's happening. Has anyone ever experienced this? MenuItems with set commands also get disabled for some reason. Unset MenuItems don't. You can see that the "Exit" MenuItem shown above is disabled. In the code below it's set to "ApplicationCommands.Close".

By the way, I'm using Windows 7 x64 and writing the WPF app with Visual Studio 2010. A helping hand will be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
<Window x:Class="TestDrive.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Header="Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Image is missing, as is code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't notice that I wasn't allowed to post images yet. The code is pretty basic. Since it's a new project I made to test the problem I haven't even done much to it other than add the menus.

Comment: The code works just fine here, menu is appearing correctly. I did however change FlowDirection to RightToLeft for the File MenuItem and it then appeared like yours, but the text was right aligned... Perhaps it's a system/language setting?

Comment: Could it be some driver problems? Or maybe a problem with my .NET installation. I'm currently downloading new drivers for my laptop and I'm going to try my app on another computer (still waiting for the installation of .NET 4 to complete though). I tried searching the net for similar problems but I couldn't find any who have experienced the same.

Comment: Your screen shot shows you are using "Windows Phone 7 Emulator" but your question refers to WPF.  Which platform are you really trying to target?

Comment: @Tom: That was one of my hunches. I also tried switching it and it did change but it was still wrong even for the reverse. My current languages installed in this computer is English and Japanese. Both have left-to-right as standard making it rather confusing. It would have been a different story if I had Arabic installed.

Comment: @Rick: That dropdown for the emulator is disabled. I'm working on a Windows app with WPF for the UI.

Comment: I also forgot to add that when I put commands for the menuitem they become disabled too. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is an old post but the problem is similar to the one I had a few weeks ago and I solved it via this route.

Windows has a Touch/TabletPCs setting where you can fill in whether you are left or right handed. This determines the positioning of the contextmenu to make sure your hand is not covering the menu in case of touchscreen devices which is causing the problem.

Go to Control Panel --> Hardware and Sounds --> Tablet PC's. And choose left-handed in the third tab called 'Other'. This will position the menu on the other side of the menubutton.

**EDITED**

It seems that both DevilFisch and I are using a Wacom pen tablet which could be the cause of this issue. When using a pentablet or something alike, Tablet PC settings are triggered causing the afformentioned issues.

Comment: It's been a while since I've been to my past questions so I didn't notice that you wrote an answer. I just went back here to update my answer to reflect what you said which I found out independently a while ago. I was surprised that someone already beat me to it! Haha! Anyway, I realized this when I noticed the problem again today on my PC and tablet. I use a Wacom pen on my PC and the tablet obviously has a touchscreen. Those hardware additions probably caused the tablet PC settings to change accordingly. I'm deleting my old answer and switching the answer to yours.

Comment: Ah that also answers my question as to why it was an issue on my PC aswell. I also use a Wacom tablet (intuos 5 touch). It is possible that that changed the settings.

Comment: Looks like we've found the real "culprit" then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding commands resulting in disabled menu items, that is expected if there is no corresponding command binding. As for the alignment issue, have you tried not setting explicit sizes in your XAML? For example:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDrive.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Header="Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I tried the exact code above and the result is the same. I'm now starting to think that it might be a problem with my computer. Maybe drivers or some software causing .Net to go haywire. Still, I'm not giving up. I wanted to try running my app on my other PC but .Net fails with a Access Denied error for some reason. If it runs fine there then the problem is a local one. I just hope I can find it without uninstalling everything.